# Write file name on text layer in Adobe Illustrator using script

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have a script and I want to add some new features to it.

First I have a layer (IntialSetup, Icons, ExportLayer,).
The script places the icons on the target layer specified in the (IntialSetup) layer.

[image: View layer setup]

As you can see in the picture, I want to give the names of the substrates in the (Business) word (Icons) layer.

Comment: What's the question? You've told us what you want to achieve, but not what you've tried so far and where the problem is. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54551683/edit) and do so?

Comment: No problem, I'm looking for a person who can make additions and pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to paste a name of your file into an existed text frame? It can be done pretty easy:

```
app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].contents = app.activeDocument.name;
```

Variant with no extension:

```
app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].contents =
app.activeDocument.name.split(".").slice(0,-1).join(".");
```